# Query to count record with one query based on multiple and different where condition?

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem with my laravel count code, Please check the code to count the record.

```
       /**
        *
        *These Are constants
        *Record::StatusVerified = 1
        *Record::StatusReject = 2
        *Record::StatusUnverified = 0
        *
        */
        $allCity = City::get();
        $rowData = [];
        foreach ($allCity as $val) {
            $content = [];
            $record  = Records::where(['city' => $val->id]);
       // other filters

            $statusVerified = $record->where(['status' => Record::StatusVerified])->count();
            $statusRejected = $record->where(['status' => Record::StatusReject])->count();
            $statusUnverified = $record->where(['status' => Record::StatusUnverified])->count();
            $content['verified'] = $statusVerified;
            $content['Rejected'] = $statusRejected;
            $content['Unverified'] = $statusUnverified;
            $rowData[] = $content;
        }

        //pur row to CSV file
```

In this code I am trying to get count of record based on city and count of total record with where condition of status.
But only the first count give correct record but other give zero(0) count.
I try to put $record variable into another variable and then try to get count but still the same problem.

```
$newVariable = $record;
$content['verified'] = $newVariable->where(['status' => Record::StatusVerified])->count();
$content['Rejected'] = $newVariable->where(['status' => Record::StatusRejected])->count();
$content['Unverified'] = $newVariable->where(['status' => Record::StatusUnverified])->count();
```

I even created 3 variable $verified, $unverified and $rejected and then assign variable $record to them then try to get count with these 3 variable.

```
$verified = $unverified = $rejected = $record;
$content['verified'] = $verified->where(['status' => Record::StatusVerified])->count();
$content['Rejected'] = $rejected->where(['status' => Record::StatusRejected])->count();
$content['Unverified'] = $unverified->where(['status' => Record::StatusUnverified])->count();
```

But still it give me correct in first one and zero(0) in other two.
So I have to write full query for all 3 record, I can use other function to call full query with variable pass but I have a situation that I can't becase so many other filter are included in the query and if I do create new function with so many variable pass the code will look ugly.

Comment: why do i have to add += to add all verified into one i don't want that, I need multiple row this is not the problem. The problem is that query give count 0 even if i remove foreach loop it does not have effect on the query. the loop is only for city not for count. I need count based on status not based on city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is this:

```
$verified = $unverified = $rejected = $record;
```

All those variables refer to the same query object. Now this first line is gonna work:

```
$content['verified'] = $verified->where(['status' => Record::StatusVerified])->count();
```

However, in the second statement:

```
$content['Rejected'] = $rejected->where(['status' => Record::StatusRejected])->count();
```

It doesn't work because `$verified` and `$rejected` refer to the same query. `$rejected` add one more condition to the previous query and the underlying query is some thing like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM records
WHERE city = 'some_city_id'
AND status = 'verified'
AND status = 'rejected'
```

Now the above query clearly return zero, because there's no records that have both statuses.

The best approach in my opinion is simply use `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), status FROM records
GROUP BY status
WHERE city = 'some_city_id'
AND status in (‘verified', ‘rejected’, ‘unverified’)
```

Or a "quick and dirty" approach (which I don't recommend) is to clone the initial query:

```
$verified = clone $record;
$unverified = clone $record;
$rejected = clone $record;
$content['verified'] = $verified->where(['status' => Record::StatusVerified])->count();
$content['Rejected'] = $rejected->where(['status' => Record::StatusRejected])->count();
$content['Unverified'] = $unverified->where(['status' => Record::StatusUnverified])->count();
```

Comment: Yes, I already though about group by that give me 3 record, but is there any other way to do it?